# Android VideoView - youtube loading only 3gp files

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-youtube-api, android-videoview

I am trying to develop an android application which must play an youtube video in a VideoView.

So I got the following piece of code. Its working well **but only playing low resolution 3gp format even if my video having HD content.**

Can any one help me ? There is any idea for solving this

Tested on Nexus5, Samsung s4

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    public String videoUrl;
    public VideoView videoView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        //setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        new YourAsyncTask().execute();


    }
    private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(VideoActivity.this, "", "Loading Video wait...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bt6sYrI18J4";
                videoUrl = getUrlVideoRTSP(url);
                Log.e("Video url for playing=========>>>>>", videoUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Login Soap Calling in Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(VideoActivity.this);
            videoView.setMediaController(mc);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();          
            mc.show();
        }

    }

    public static String getUrlVideoRTSP(String urlYoutube)
    {
        try
        {
            String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
            URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
            Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");///media:content
            String cursor = urlYoutube;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = list.item(i);
                if (node != null)
                {
                    NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                    HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++)
                    {
                        Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                        maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                    }
                    if (maps.containsKey("yt:format"))
                    {
                        String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                        if (maps.containsKey("url"))
                        {
                            cursor = maps.get("url");
                        }
                        if (f.equals("1"))
                            return cursor;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cursor;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Get Url Video RTSP Exception======>>", ex.toString());
        }
        return urlYoutube;

    }

    protected static String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        String id = null;
        try
        {
            String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
            if (query != null)
            {
                String[] param = query.split("&");
                for (String row : param)
                {
                    String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                    if (param1[0].equals("v"))
                    {
                        id = param1[1];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (url.contains("embed"))
                {
                    id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
        }
        return id;
    }


}
```

Comment: Use android youtube api..

Comment: THanks for your reply. Can you please show me a tutorial or code for the same ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Search it google. Google is better then me.